# line break for list in sencha

Tags: list, sencha-touch-2

I am creating a list where i am adding elements to the list. Now, if i add a text to the list which is one long sentence with no linebreaks, it just goes out of scope.

[image: The third element, this is how it looks after being added to the list]

[image: That is the actual text thats supposed to be added to the list]

What I want is that, if the word is too long, i shud explicitly break it so that it comes in the next line. I am not sure on how to do that.

```
{
            cls:'notesList',
            xtype:'list',
            id:'notesList',
            height:300,
            whitespace:pre-wrap,
            allowDeselect: false,
            style:'background-color: rgba(0,140,153,1.0);',
            itemTpl:'<table><tr><td width="3%"><img src="resources/images/user.png" width="20em" height="20em" /></td>' +
                '<td width = "60%" style="font-weight:bold;text-align:left;">{Author}</td>' +
                '<td width = "40%" style="font-weight:bold;text-align: right">{Name}</td></tr>'+
                '<tr><td colspan=3>{Text}</td></tr></table>'
        },
```

Comment: I don't know anything about Sencha (or very little, just getting started), but maybe you can specify some max-width in css and then the text will adjust automatically?

Comment: If you haven't found an answer yet, just create a Sencha Fiddle and I'll take a look.

Comment: http://www.senchafiddle.com/#U8 I have shared my code here. But the code is not running as of now cause i am new to fiddle. This tool looks interesting. Please help me understand the tool better.

Comment: http://www.senchafiddle.com/#U8s0e is the edited link.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem once, and I solve it by adding some CSS to the container of the text.

Add a CSS class to the item of your list by using the itemCls config on your list.

Then add the following to this CSS class in your .css

```
word-wrap: break-word;
overflow: hidden;
max-width: 247px;
width: 247px;
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Hey @Knush add this instructions to yours element `white-space:pre-wrap` can you specific `width` to `input text`.

For example,

Into `style`

```
....
items: [
{
    text: '<p class="your_class" face="Arial" size="2" style="text-align:center;white-space:pre-wrap;" >lkjsdlksdj ewiouwe iouiuio</p>',
    id: 'ce',
    handler: function() {
        stuff()
    },
},
 ]
...
```

Or from CSS class

```
.your_label {
   width: 60px;
   white-space:pre-wrap;
}
```

I hope this helps. :)

Comment: hey, can u elaborate. I dont think I got it completely.

Comment: Show me how do you doing please.

Comment: Oh I see, no, no the `white-space:pre-wrap` going to into `style`. I update my answer. ;)